# Socket.IO works with Firefox and Edge but doesn't work with Chrome?

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

I'm fairly new to Python and i'm trying to build something on Flask/Socket.IO. Before starting, i decided to study [this example](https://github.com/shanealynn/async_flask). I tested it on Firefox and Edge and it wors perfectly, i get the numbers in real-time, but on Chrome i will only get the page without the numbers. I opened my console and there is nothing, it looks like the Socket won't connect to Chrome. I made some research and could not find any similar issue, any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Flask uses Adobe Flash right?  If so, flash may be disabled by default in Chrome.  Why not use the webSocket based socket.io on the browser side of things?

Comment: Looks like the problem is not with Adobe Flash. What do you mean using the websocket based socket.io? Thanks!

Comment: I believe chrome has disabled socket.io due to security issues or not fully supporting it. This has nothing to do with Adobe Flash.

Comment: @yoonghm - That is not correct.  Chrome does not disable socket.io.  They disable Adobe Flash in some circumstances.

Comment: That was why I said it has nothing to do with Adobe Flash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Google Chrome do you use? I just tested on my "**Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64 bit)**" and it works very well.

So considering that you have the same (or higher) version of Chrome, try this:

Delete your browsing data (images and cached files) and refresh the page. There may be a conflict between cached files and files loaded from CDNs in your HTML page.

If it still does not work, try this:

In your **templates/index.html** file, replace line `<script src="static/js/application.js"></script>` with `<script src="{{url_for('static',filename='js/application.js')}}"></script>` to load the javascript file. Finally reload the server. See [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/static/) for more details on how to load a static file into flask.

I hope this will help.